# CartoCSS markers

Tags: tilemill, mapnik, cartocss

I want to put markers (circle) on my map render defined in cartocss tilemill. But on zoom levels 4-5-6 I have problem that render displays markers without city name, because there is no enough space for city name.
Is there an option that forces to display both marker and city name or none of them?

Answer (score 1):

Use `shield` instead of `text` + `marker` combo. Note that for text offset you would need to use `shield-text-dx`, not `shield-dx`.

Comment: Very helpful. `shield-unlock-image: true;`  is also necessary to offset the text.